# Finalidade de um WebService

Tags: web-service, sistemas-distribuídos

Bem, sempre vejo na internet ou até ouço amigos conversando sobre `WebServices`, já li algumas coisas relacionadas ao assunto mas ainda não consegui entender muito bem. Eu sei que com um `WebService` posso fazer a interação de vários sistemas. Mas não seria mais fácil eu conectar todos esses sistemas em apenas um banco de dados e pegar todos os dados do mesmo?

Comment: Geralmente os webservices e os clientes não usam o mesmo banco, webservice é usado para você enviar dados para outro servidor de maneira padronizada sem necessitar de uma interação do usuário direta. Por exemplo você pode enviar produtos para o mercadolivre usando REST. Ou seja você pode criar um sistema PHP para o seu cliente e ele não precisa acessar o mercadolivre para enviar os produtos. WebServices são usados também para Apps de celulares, para salvar os dados no servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mas não seria mais fácil eu conectar todos esses sistemas em apenas um banco de dados e pegar todos os dados do mesmo?

## Não.

O motivo é que se você der acesso ao banco de dados, a sua segurança, suas regras de negócio e seu encapsulamento são comprometidos.

Imagine que o site A é uma transportadora e o site B é uma empresa de vendas de mercadorias. Os clientes acessam o site B para fazer compras e o site da empresa B conversa com o site A por meio de um webservice para agendar a entrega das mercadorias e para obter o custo do frete a ser cobrado do usuário.

Mas, vamos supor que ao invés disso, o site A abra o acesso ao banco de dados para a empresa B. Neste caso a empresa B poderia obter acesso a dados de outros clientes da transportadora, poderia cadastrar, alterar e destruir informações das quais não é dona, inclusive de outros clientes da transportadora. O resultado disso seria o caos.

Há a questão das regras de negócio da empresa A. Com o acesso direto ao banco de dados pela empresa B, quem na empresa A pode garantir que o processo na empresa B não vai cadastrar entregas em cidades não-atendidas? Uma vez que a empresa B tem acesso ao banco de dados de A, todas as regras de negócio de A terão sido contornadas.

Além disso, vamos supor que para calcular o frete, a empresa A precise coletar dados de 27 tabelas diferentes. Porque que a empresa B precisa saber disso se a única coisa que eles querem é o valor do frete? A empresa B não quer saber como é que o preço da gasolina em diferentes regiões do país e como os custos de pedágios afeta o preço do frete, pois isso é responsabilidade da empresa A. O que a empresa B quer saber é apenas qual seria o preço do frete. Esse preço é algo que o webservice da empresa A pode informar, e o que está por trás deste webservice é problema e responsabilidade da empresa A. Mas se ao invés disso for usado o acesso direto ao banco de dados, então a empresa B precisaria executar todos estes processos nas 27 tabelas da empresa A, o que não deveria ser responsabilidade deles.

Além disso, mesmo se a empresa B for bem-comportada, a empresa A não poderá fazer mudanças no seu banco de dados facilmente sem quebrar as coisas para a empresa B e para todos os outros clientes que detém do acesso ao seu banco de dados. Se alguém invadir o site da empresa B, o banco de dados da empresa A também estaria comprometido e junto com ele, o de todos os outros clientes da empresa A.

O melhor então é que a empresa A disponibilize um webservice publicando as operações a serem realizadas. Desta forma, a implementação do banco de dados fica restrita a própria empresa A. Se ela quiser fazer alterações no banco de dados para usar informações sobre borracharias nas estradas para calcular o frete, basta eles fazerem algumas mudanças na implementação do serviço para garantir a compatibilidade e a empresa B nem sequer precisa ficar sabendo que houve algum tipo de mudança porque realmente não é problema deles.

Além disso, com o webservice, você garante que as regras de negócio serão respeitadas e que a empresa B só conseguirá ter acesso a aquilo que lhes interessem da forma como de fato deveriam ter. Se a empresa B tentar cadastrar uma entrega em uma cidade que não é atendida, o webservice devolve um erro. Com o webservice você também pode fazer validações e verificações (inclusive de login/senha). Além disso, a empresa B não precisa saber (e nem vai querer saber) como é que faz para extrair e juntar dados de 27 diferentes tabelas para calcular o frete, pois isso é responsabilidade da empresa A e a empresa B não tem nada a ver com isso.

E nem tudo se limita ao banco de dados, imagina que no cálculo do trajeto para a entrega na empresa A exista um processo que depende da geração e manipulação de alguns arquivos. E aí, iria abrir o sistema de arquivos para os outros também?

Comment: Complementando a resposta, webservices são feitos justamente para que haja uma independência entre a equipe de interface, e a equipe de backend. Ambos, podem prosseguir com o seu desenvolvimento independente de outro, para que no fim, haja a "fusão".

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta e pelo comentário, foram bastantes esclarecedores.