# Controle de transações entre duas aplicações distintas

Tags: java, c#, oracle, transações

estou trabalhando em uma aplicação que é divida em dois módulos, cada um em uma linguagem (.NET e Java).

A aplicação A (.NET) irá manipular os registros de uma tabela enquanto a aplicação B (Java) fará a manipulação na mesma ao mesmo tempo.

> Cenário: Imaginem que tenho uma estrutura de Cliente e Saldo na conta.
>
> Quando o cliente não existir, ambas as aplicações podem cadastrá-lo.
>   Para que o cliente não seja duplicado no banco de dados, foi criado uma unique no banco de dados (Oracle).

Até aqui tudo bem, não existirá o cliente duas vezes. O problema começa quando ambas as aplicações forem fazer as movimentações na conta do cliente.

Exemplo: Imaginem que a aplicação .Net faz um depósito de R$ 50,00. Neste momento o registro na tabela ficará com 50 de saldo. Porém se ao mesmo tempo deste depósito, fosse feito uma rotina que retira R$ 10,00 de saldo deste cliente.

Eu precisaria controlar a transação entre duas aplicações, ou seja, se fosse feito um depósito de R$ 50,00 e um saque de R$ 10,00 ao mesmo tempo (hipoteticamente falando), o saldo final do cliente deveria ser R$ 40,00.

O cenário que tenho hoje, as aplicações recuperam o registro do cliente, efetuam o cálculo e devolvem para a tabela o valor atualizado, porém está havendo uma sobreposição dos dados. Por exemplo, a transação .NET lança saldo de R$ 50,00 e a aplicação Java lança saque de R$ 10,00 ao mesmo tempo. Quanto a aplicação .NET recupera o registro centralizado do cliente, ele tem 0 de saldo, assim como a aplicação Java também. Se a aplicação .NET terminar primeiro, ela lança 50 de saldo e depois a aplicação Java lança 10 de saque, ficando o registro na tabela de -10.

Existe alguma forma de controlar isto entre as duas aplicações somente com transação cada aplicação com a sua? Estive pensando e imaginei um cenário onde deveria haver um serviço utilizando *LOCK* para tratar este tipo de operação. Imaginam outra forma de resolver?

Observação: é um sistema legado, alterar a forma de armazenamento do saldo seria praticamente inviável.

Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Bem, a sugestão mais óbvia seria adicionar uma coluna para fazer um lock otimista (veja exemplos disso [aqui](http://blog.algaworks.com/entendendo-o-lock-otimista-do-jpa/) e [aqui](http://archsofty.blogspot.com/2009/10/jpa-lock-otimista-e-pessimista.html), também é fácil achar mais exemplos no google).

Entretanto, como isso é um sistema legado onde é difícil ou impossível mexer na estrutura do banco de dados, acho que a melhor sugestão é a seguinte:

1. Crie uma aplicação (vamos chamar ela de X) que tem acesso exclusivo ao banco de dados e que o controla com exclusividade.
2. A aplicação X conhece e garante as regras de negócio do uso do banco de dados.
3. A aplicação X poderia então disponibilizar os serviço providos pelo banco de dados por meio de REST, webservices, sockets, etc. O importante é que X deve expor apenas operações que permitam que o banco de dados seja alterado ou consultado de formas que façam sentido para as regras de negócio do sistema. Ou seja, nada de disponibilizar um serviço de update genérico ou algo que receba instruções SQLs diretamente.
4. Modificar as demais aplicações (vamos chamá-las de A e B) para que todas elas só possam ter acesso aos dados por meio da aplicação X. As demais aplicações ficariam então sumariamente proibidas de se conectarem diretamente ao banco de dados.

Essa abordagem elimina o seu problema fundamental, que é o de ter duas aplicações acesssando o banco de dados ao mesmo tempo. É verdade que você ganha um novo problema, que é o de necessitar de uma aplicação a mais para controlar tudo isso (e de certa forma dá para dizer que você transformou um problema A em um outro problema B apenas). Entretanto, nessa aplicação X, você passa a ter o controle total no acesso aos dados e nas regras de negócio do sistema, algo que você não tinha quando as aplicações iam todas diretamente ao banco de dados. Isso também te ajuda a centralizar e unificar as regras de negócio, eliminando com isso, muita duplicação de esforços resultante do fato de ter as mesmas regras de negócio implementadas em dois ou mais lugares diferentes e garantindo também que a implementação dessas regras seja a mesma para todos (pois ela estará em um único lugar).

É óbvio que essa abordagem daria um trabalhão para ser implementada por completo, mas é possível implementá-la em etapas ou apenas parcialmente nas partes onde isso for necessário. Escolha os casos mais críticos (por exemplo, esse da alteração do saldo do cliente) e coloque-o na aplicação X e altere tanto a aplicação A quanto a B para utilizar a aplicação X nesse caso. Em seguida, escolha outra funcionalidade e faça o mesmo. Faça isso até que todas as funcionalidades estejam dentro da aplicação X (ou pelo menos todas as funcionalidades para as quais você julgue que valha o esforço de fazer isso).

Por fim, dependendo de como estiver as suas aplicações, pode ser mais fácil eleger uma delas (vamos dizer que seja a A) para ser o X e fazer a outra (B) acessar a primeira. Ou então pode ser mais fácil pegar uma delas (A) e dividir em duas: o X e a aplicação original A, fazendo a B acessar a X.

Recomendo ler [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73059/132) e também [a minha resposta lá](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73133/132).

Comment: opa Victor, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Esta seria a única opção? Será que as aplicações separadas pelo banco não consiga fazer algo? tipo Transaction, etc

Comment: @LeoLimas Sim, deve haver mais um monte de possíveis soluções. Mas vez que você mesmo colocou as tags [oracle] e [transações] na questão, eu imagino que uma resposta do tipo "*É só utilizar as transações do oracle.*" não seja aquilo que você espera como resposta.