# O que é um Sistema Distribuído

Tags: terminologia, sistemas-distribuídos

Na minha aula de sistema distribuídos é abordado assuntos a respeito de web-services SOAP e REST e outros assuntos a respeito deste campo. Entretanto, eu não consigo entender o que de fato é um ***Sistema Distribuído***, não sei se é uma combinação de diversas tecnologias ou serviços.

## Pergunta

- O que é um Sistema Distribuído?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Programação Concorrente x Paralela x Distribuída](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75727/programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-concorrente-x-paralela-x-distribu%c3%adda)

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza a resposta não sanou minha dúvida, ela é focada em um estilo de programação do que na concepção de um sistema distribuído ou a arquitetura dele. Poderia até ser relacionado.

Comment: Nesse caso se opõe a um sistema centralizado. Estou na correria aqui, não vou conseguir responder tão cedo

Comment: Leitura complementar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73059/132

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um sistema distribuído é um sistema que tem diversos nós que executam paralelamente, processamento de dados. Os nós não precisam necessariamente ter papéis homogêneos na tarefa desempenhada, sendo muito comum a heterogeneidade.

Podem ser considerados dentre os tipos de sistemas distribuídos:

- Sistemas de computação em nuvem.
- IoT - Internet das coisas.
- Sistemas P2P.
- Botnets.
- Sistemas que colaboram entre si de forma integrada por meio de troca de mensagens.
- Criptomoedas.
- etc.

A regra aqui é que há várias partes do sistema conversando de forma integrada. Diversos protocolos podem ser utilizados para governar a comunicação desses. Os mais comuns no presente são o SOAP (junto com tecnologias relacionadas tais como WS-*, WSDL, UDDI, entre outras) e o REST (que se aproveita do HTTP). Há e houve outras tecnologias nesse sentido, tal como o CORBA (que, ainda bem, está caindo em desuso). A integração pode ser feita até via e-mail, FTP, sockets TCP ou UDP.

A estrutura do sistema como um todo frequentemente é uma orquestração, onde um dos nós inicia e coordena a operação como um todo sendo que os demais nós apenas realizam tarefas específicas (podendo eles mesmos serem também orquestrações). Uma outra estrutura é a de coreografia, onde os serviços conversam entre si mas sem que haja um controle ou uma coordenação central.

Em alguns casos, um mesmo nó (ou pool de nós) pode fazer parte de múltiplos sistemas distribuídos. Por exemplo, o sistema da empresa A pode conversar com o sistema dos correios para mapear CEPs para ruas. Enquanto isso, a empresa B, que não tem nenhuma relação com a empresa A, pode fazer o mesmo.

Comment: Os sites da Stack Exchange seria um exemplo de sistema distribuído?

Comment: @gato Provavelmente não. Ele aparenta ser apenas um sistema web comum. Entretanto, nada te impede de criar um sistema distribuído que utilize alguma coisa da APIs do StackExchange para executar seu trabalho.

Comment: @gato fica difícil dizer. O fato de serem dois sites distintos não quer dizer que sejam servidores distribuídos. O Facebook escala em vários computadores para servir todo o mundo, então o Facebook usa um sistema distribuído para atender isso